# What do all the letters and numbers in a Red Hat RPM version number mean e.g. openssl-devel-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1?

Tags: rhel, rpm, openssl, version

What do all the letters and numbers in the rpm name openssl-devel-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1 mean?  I recognize the openssl-devel-0.9.8e part because that's the same number applied by the developement team at openssl.org.  But what do the numbers and letters in the 27.el5_10.1 part mean?

I've googled and searched on Red Hat's web site for an explanation.  The best explanation I've found is https://access.redhat.com/site/security/updates/backporting/ but it doesn't really go into the version string scheme/format.

Context: We're developing software which compiles and links against openssl, so our code depends on openssl-devel.  To make this convenient, we repackage some binaries from the openssl-devel installation (e.g. /usr/lib/libssl.a) as a maven artifact and upload the artifact to a private maven repo.  Maven artifacts have version numbers, so I'm planning to version it identically to its RPM source.  I'd like to simplify the version string a bit for example, if I know that all the 27.x versions of openssl-devel-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1 will be compile and link compatible then I could get by with a simpler artifact version of 0.9.8e-27 rather than the full 0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1.

Comment: "I'd like to simplify the version string a bit for example, if I know that all the 27.x versions of openssl-devel-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1 will be compile and link compatible" Part of the value Red Hat is providing people is that kind of guarantee within the same major version number. For example RHEL6 and RHEL7 may differ drastically, but RHEL6.0 and RHEL6.5 are supposed to basically be the same OS just with minor tweaks and bug fixes. They make mistakes and sometimes ignore that goal, but that's the assumption they've promised to try to uphold.

Comment: There's typically some kind of brouhaha whenever Red Hat does change something people consider non-trivial between minor versions, but ever since RHEL5 they seem to have started behaving themselves.

Comment: That said, I'm posting comments because I don't know the answer, but I don't think patch versioning is going to matter for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maximum RPM book has a page on naming conventions in the File Format section, which can be seen here:

http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-file-format.html#S1-RPM-FILE-FORMAT-FILE-NAMING-CONVENTION

There is also some information on the fedora site. I'm not sure if you have already seen this, but here is the link:

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s03.html

Comment: the rpm link is outdated

Comment: Link has been updated.